# How to use npm scripts within javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, npm

I need a complete guide or a good reference material to solve the running module commands within javascript file problem.

Say that I often run:

```
$ npm run webpack-dev-server --progress --colors -- files
```

How can I run this within a javascript file and execute with

```
$ node ./script.js
```

**script.js**

```
var webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

// need help here
var result = webpackDevServer.execute({
  progress: true,
  colors: true,
}, files);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Answer

I do something like this for my Webpack bundles. You can simply use `child_process.spawn` to execute command-line programs and handle the process in a node script.

Here's an example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn

// ...

// Notice how your arguments are in an array of strings
var child = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server', [
    '--progress',
    '--colors',
    '<YOUR ENTRY FILE>'
]);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
});

child.on('exit', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write('I\'m done!');
});
```

[You can handle all of the events you like.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) This is a fairly powerful module that allows you to view the process' PID (`child.pid`) and even kill the process whenever you choose (`child.kill()`).

---

## Addendum

A neat trick is to throw everything into a `Promise`. Here's a simplified example of what my version of `script.js` would look like:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var child = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/webpack', [
            '-d'
        ]);

        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            process.stdout.write(data);
        });

        child.on('error', function (data) {
            reject('Webpack errored!');
        });

        child.on('exit', function () {
            resolve('Webpack completed successfully');
        });
    });
}
```

Using this method, you can include your `script.js` in other files and make this code synchronous in your build system or whatever. The possibilities are endless!

---

**Edit** The `child_process.exec` also lets you execute command-line programs:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

// ...

var child = exec('webpack-dev-server --progress --colors <YOUR ENTRY FILES>',
  function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: that's awesome, is there anyway i can do this without spawn?

Comment: @user2167582 Yep! You can use `child_process.exec` see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work on Windows and doesn't handle exit codes, so here's a fully featured and more concise version.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const path = require('path')

function webpackDevServer() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let child = spawn(
            path.resolve('./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server'),
            [ '--progress', '--colors' ],
            { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' }
        )
        
        child.on('error', reject)
        child.on('exit', (code) => code === 0 ? resolve() : reject(code))
    })
}
```

`path.resolve()` properly formats the path to the script, regardless of the host OS.

The last parameter to `spawn()` does two things. `shell: true` uses the shell, which appends `.cmd` on Windows, if necessary and `stdio: 'inherit'` passes through stdout and stderr, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Also, the exit code is important, especially when running linters and whatnot, so anything other than 0 gets rejected, just like in shell scripts.

Lastly, the `error` event occurs when the command fails to execute. When using the shell, the error is unfortunately always empty (`undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be webpack-dev-server?  There is an equivalent webpack-dev-middleware for running within node/express:

```
'use strict';
let express = require('express');
let app = new express();

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

let webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig), {}));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Server running on port 3000...`));
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware

Comment: the problem im trying to solve has less to do with webpack but with a way to run npm modules within javascript files, so that i can invoke compositioned macro commands via node ./myscript.js